# How to draw the curvy lines in the following latex figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
    \usepackage{pst-all}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}


\tikzset{every path/.style=thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
        thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=.13cm
       }}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\begin{scope}
\begin{scope}



           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{1}]{};


           \node (a2) at (1.5,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{2}]{};
           \node (a3) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:\scriptsize{3}]{};
           \node (a9) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:\scriptsize{9}]{};
           \node (a7) at (.75,3) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{7}]{};
           \node (a4) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{4}]{};

           \node (a5) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{5}]{};
           \node (a6) at (3.8,3) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{6}]{};
           \node (a8) at (.75,4.5) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{8}]{};
           \node (a10) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{10}]{};
           \node (a11) at (-.75,3) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{11}]{};
           \node (a12) at (-2.2,3) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{12}]{};
           \node (a13) at (1.7,4.5) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{13}]{};
           \node (a14) at (2.8,4.5) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{14}]{};

            \draw  (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw  (a3) -- (a4);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a5);
            \draw  (a5) -- (a6);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a7);
            \draw  (a7) -- (a8);
            \draw  (a9) -- (a10);
            \draw [dashed] (a9) -- (a11);
            \draw (a11) -- (a12);
            \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a9);
            \draw [dashed] (a9) -- (a7);
            \draw [dashed] (a13) -- (a7);
            \draw (a13) -- (a14);
           \node at (.75,-1) {\textit{$U_1$}}; 

\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{1}]{}; 


           \node (a2) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{2}]{};
           \node (a3) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{4}]{};
           \node (a5) at (3,3) [acteur,label=below right:\scriptsize{5}]{};
           \node (a6) at (4.5,3) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{6}]{};

           \node (a7) at (2.25,5) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{7}]{};
           \node (a8) at (3.5,5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{8}]{};
           \node (a9) at (4.75,5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{9}]{};
           \node (a10) at (6,5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{10}]{};
            \node (a11) at (7.25,5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{11}]{};
            \node (a15) at (1.2,6.5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{15}]{};
            \node (a16) at (0,6.5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{16}]{};
           \node (a17) at (3.3,6.5) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{17}]{};
           \node (a18) at (4.76,6.5) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{18}]{};

           \node (a12) at (2.25,6.5) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{12}]{};

           \node (a13) at (1.5,3) [acteur,label=below left:\scriptsize{13}]{};
           \node (a14) at (0,3) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{14}]{};



            \draw (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw (a3) -- (a4);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a5);
            \draw (a5) -- (a6);
            \draw  [dashed](a5) -- (a7);
            \draw [dashed] (a17) -- (a8);
            \draw  (a8) -- (a9);
            \draw  [dashed](a9) -- (a10);
            \draw  (a10) -- (a11);
            \draw  (a7) -- (a12);
            \draw [dashed] (a7) -- (a13);
            \draw  (a13) -- (a14);
            \draw  [dashed](a2) -- (a13);
            \draw  [dashed](a7) -- (a15);
            \draw  (a15) -- (a16);
            \draw  [dashed](a7) -- (a17);
            \draw  (a17) -- (a18);
           \node at (2.25,-1) {\textit{$U_2$}}; 
\end{scope} 

\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{The solid edges are the matching edges. The graph $U_1$ lies in $S_1$ while $U_2$ lies in $S_2$. }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw the following figure in Latex. I have drawn it almost but I am not able to draw those curvy line at the respective vertices as shown in the figure attached. How to draw such curve?

Comment: My code is fine. But I am not able to give those curvy lines in the respective vertices. Please help

Comment: There is the `random steps` decoration for that purpose.

Comment: Please give the code for that IF POSSIBLE. tHANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

I added the curvy lines to the left part of your picture, the right part is left as an exercise (also because I like the fact that "the right part is left" is not always a nonsensical statement ;-). To this end, I added a style `curvy line`, which is based on the `random steps` decoration, and you may adjust the `segment length`, `amplitude` and `rounded corners` to your likings. A single curvy line can be drawn with

```
\draw[curvy line] (a3) -- ++ (80:1.7);
```

see the examples in

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every path/.style=thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
        thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=.13cm
       },
       curvy line/.style={decorate,,rounded corners=2pt,decoration={random steps,segment length=3mm,
       amplitude=1mm}}}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7,every label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\begin{scope}
\begin{scope}



           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:{1}]{};


           \node (a2) at (1.5,0) [acteur,label=below:{2}]{};
           \node (a3) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below right:{3}]{};
           \node (a9) at (0,1.5) [acteur,label=below left:{9}]{};
           \node (a7) at (.75,3) [acteur,label=right:{7}]{};
           \node (a4) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=right:{4}]{};

           \node (a5) at (2.25,3) [acteur,label=above:{5}]{};
           \node (a6) at (3.8,3) [acteur,label=right:{6}]{};
           \node (a8) at (.75,4.5) [acteur,label=above:{8}]{};
           \node (a10) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=left:{10}]{};
           \node (a11) at (-.75,3) [acteur,label=above:{11}]{};
           \node (a12) at (-2.2,3) [acteur,label=left:{12}]{};
           \node (a13) at (1.7,4.5) [acteur,label=above:{13}]{};
           \node (a14) at (2.8,4.5) [acteur,label=right:{14}]{};

            \draw  (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw  (a3) -- (a4);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a5);
            \draw  (a5) -- (a6);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a7);
            \draw  (a7) -- (a8);
            \draw  (a9) -- (a10);
            \draw [dashed] (a9) -- (a11);
            \draw (a11) -- (a12);
            \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a9);
            \draw [dashed] (a9) -- (a7);
            \draw [dashed] (a13) -- (a7);
            \draw (a13) -- (a14);
           \node at (.75,-1) {$U_1$}; 
% curvy lines
   \draw[curvy line] (a3) -- ++ (80:1.7);          
   \draw[curvy line] (a3) -- ++ (-60:1.7);             
   \draw[curvy line] (a7) -- ++ (30:1.7);          
   \draw[curvy line] (a7) -- ++ (150:1.7);             
   \draw[curvy line] (a9) -- ++ (90:1.7);          
   \draw[curvy line] (a9) -- ++ (-120:1.7);            
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:{1}]{}; 


           \node (a2) at (1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=below:{2}]{};
           \node (a3) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=below:{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (4.5,0) [acteur,label=below:{4}]{};
           \node (a5) at (3,3) [acteur,label=below right:{5}]{};
           \node (a6) at (4.5,3) [acteur,label=right:{6}]{};

           \node (a7) at (2.25,5) [acteur,label=left:{7}]{};
           \node (a8) at (3.5,5) [acteur,label=below:{8}]{};
           \node (a9) at (4.75,5) [acteur,label=below:{9}]{};
           \node (a10) at (6,5) [acteur,label=below:{10}]{};
            \node (a11) at (7.25,5) [acteur,label=below:{11}]{};
            \node (a15) at (1.2,6.5) [acteur,label=below:{15}]{};
            \node (a16) at (0,6.5) [acteur,label=below:{16}]{};
           \node (a17) at (3.3,6.5) [acteur,label=above:{17}]{};
           \node (a18) at (4.76,6.5) [acteur,label=below:{18}]{};

           \node (a12) at (2.25,6.5) [acteur,label=above:{12}]{};

           \node (a13) at (1.5,3) [acteur,label=below left:{13}]{};
           \node (a14) at (0,3) [acteur,label=left:{14}]{};



            \draw (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw (a3) -- (a4);
            \draw  [dashed](a3) -- (a5);
            \draw (a5) -- (a6);
            \draw  [dashed](a5) -- (a7);
            \draw [dashed] (a17) -- (a8);
            \draw  (a8) -- (a9);
            \draw  [dashed](a9) -- (a10);
            \draw  (a10) -- (a11);
            \draw  (a7) -- (a12);
            \draw [dashed] (a7) -- (a13);
            \draw  (a13) -- (a14);
            \draw  [dashed](a2) -- (a13);
            \draw  [dashed](a7) -- (a15);
            \draw  (a15) -- (a16);
            \draw  [dashed](a7) -- (a17);
            \draw  (a17) -- (a18);
           \node at (2.25,-1) {$U_2$}; 
\end{scope} 

\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{The solid edges are the matching edges. The graph $U_1$ lies in $S_1$ while $U_2$ lies in $S_2$. }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, `\textit{$U_1$}` does not make sense, use `$U_1$` instead, and you can use the `every label` style to make all labels `\scriptsize`.

If you use

```
\tikzset{curvy line/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=8.5mm,
   amplitude=1mm}}}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: ok. I will try. Can I use dotted lines in place of curvy lines. I mean the shape will be like that but the curve in this case composed of some dots or small line segments

Comment: @J.Doe You can do `\draw[dashed,curvy line] (a3) -- ++ (80:1.7);` or `\draw[dotted,curvy line] (a3) -- ++ (80:1.7);`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. And if I need some symmetrical lines, can we do that..because curvy lines are not symmetric

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry, it is becoming a bit cumbersome. These are `random steps`, so no, they are not symmetric. On the other hand, you asked me "Please give the code for that", i.e. for a code for random steps. If I would have known that they need to be symmetric, I would not have suggested random steps, nor written an answer. If I add a version that produces symmetric curvy lines (not even sure I understand what that means) then I fear there might be the next additional requirement that you didn't specify.

Comment: OK. NO PROBLEM.

Comment: @J.Doe The `snakes` decoration produces symmetric wiggles, if I understand correctly what you mean by "symmetric".

Comment: OK. I will try to draw. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. It is fine now.